# Azure Bicep / Json - not parsing JSON properly

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager, infrastructure-as-code, azure-bicep

I'm having trouble parsing in network security groups from a JSON File, so that we can create multiple NSGs using a single template

```
param NSGs array = array(json(loadTextContent('./shared-rules.json')))
resource nsg 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups@2020-05-01' = [for (ns, index) in NSGs: {
  name: ?????
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    securityRules: ????
  }
}]
```

Here is a copy of my templates file:

```
{
  "NSG-1": [
    {
      "name": "Allow_RDP_from_company_IP_address",
      "properties": {
        "description": "Allow inbound RDP from the company's IP address range.",
        "protocol": "Tcp",
        "sourceAddressPrefix": "203.0.113.0/24",
        "sourcePortRange": "*",
        "destinationAddressPrefix": "VirtualNetwork",
        "destinationPortRange": "3389",
        "access": "Allow",
        "priority": 100,
        "direction": "Inbound"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Allow_VirtualNetwork_to_Storage",
      "properties": {
        "description": "Allow outbound connections to the Azure Storage service tag.",
        "protocol": "Tcp",
        "sourceAddressPrefix": "VirtualNetwork",
        "sourcePortRange": "*",
        "destinationAddressPrefix": "Storage",
        "destinationPortRange": "*",
        "access": "Allow",
        "priority": 100,
        "direction": "Outbound"
      }
    }
  ],
  "NSG-2": [
    {
      "name": "Allow_RDP_from_company_IP_address",
      "properties": {
        "description": "Allow inbound RDP from the company's IP address range.",
        "protocol": "Tcp",
        "sourceAddressPrefix": "203.0.113.0/24",
        "sourcePortRange": "*",
        "destinationAddressPrefix": "VirtualNetwork",
        "destinationPortRange": "3389",
        "access": "Allow",
        "priority": 100,
        "direction": "Inbound"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Allow_VirtualNetwork_to_Storage",
      "properties": {
        "description": "Allow outbound connections to the Azure Storage service tag.",
        "protocol": "Tcp",
        "sourceAddressPrefix": "VirtualNetwork",
        "sourcePortRange": "*",
        "destinationAddressPrefix": "Storage",
        "destinationPortRange": "*",
        "access": "Allow",
        "priority": 100,
        "direction": "Outbound"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

There are only two lines I think I need to fill to get this working: That is the name and securityRules in the bicep template ((first code block)

That is assuming my JSON file is correct too - wondering if anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Did that work for you ?

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested, you could use the [items function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-array#items).

A sample on how to use it can be found here: [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/loops#dictionary-object).

For your use case, it should look like that:

```bicep
param sharedRules object = json(loadTextContent('./shared-rules.json'))

resource nsgs 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups@2020-05-01' = [for rule in items(sharedRules): {
  name: rule.key
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    securityRules: rule.value
  }
}]
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying with a working example! I messed with an identical problem for hours and finally got it working when I found this question/answer combo. :-) 
I recommend @InstantPirate to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your param should be an object type (dictionary) and overall would look something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/loops#dictionary-object